# Converting even indexed characters in a string to uppercase ruby

Tags: ruby

I need to convert all the even indexed characters in a string to become uppercase, while the odd indexed characters stay lowercase. I've tried this, but it keeps failing and I'm not sure why. I'd appreciate some help!

```
    for i in 0..string.length
      if (i % 2) == 0
        string[i].upcase
      else
        string[i].downcase
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 2):

There you go:

```
string = "asfewfgv"

(0...string.size).each do |i|
  string[i] = i.even? ? string[i].upcase : string[i].downcase
end

string  # => "AsFeWfGv"
```

We people don't use `for` loop usually, that's why I gave the above code. But here is correct version of yours :

```
string = "asfewfgv"

for i in 0...string.length  # here ... instead of ..
  string[i] = if (i % 2) == 0
                string[i].upcase
              else
                string[i].downcase
              end
end

string # => "AsFeWfGv"
```

You were doing it correctly, you just forgot to reassign it the string index after *upcasing* or *downcasing*.

Comment: I appreciate your help but for some reason this isn't working for me

Answer (score 2):

```
"foobar".gsub(/(.)(.?)/){$1.upcase + $2.downcase}   # => "FoObAr"
"fooba".gsub(/(.)(.?)/){$1.upcase + $2.downcase}    # => "FoObA"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems with your code:

- `for i in 0..string.length` should be for `i in 0...string.length` to make the last character evaluated `string[string.length-1]`, rather than going past the end of the string (`string[string.length]`); and
- `string[i]` must be an L-value; that is, you must have, for example, `string[i] = string[i].upcase`.

You can correct your code and make it more idiomatic as follows:

```
string = "The cat in the hat"

string.length.times do |i|
  string[i] = i.even? ? string[i].upcase : string[i].downcase
end
string
  #=> "ThE CaT In tHe hAt"
```